# Erro em constante da biblioteca DOMPDF

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel

Instalei o package da dompdf no laravel4, utilizando o composer.
Porém, está dando o seguinte erro ao tentar criar o objeto:

> Use of undefined constant DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR - assumed 'DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR'

O php sendo utilizado é o 5.3.10, laravel 4.0.10

código de criação:

```php
$pdf = new DOMPDF();
```

código do arquivo de definições da dompdf:

```php
def("DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR", sys_get_temp_dir());
```

Mesmo com alteração dessa definição ou inclusão por `include`, o erro persiste.

Alguém conhece o motivo do erro ou já passou por este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu li na documentação, você deve fazer o require do arquivo de configuração do DOMPDF, antes de instanciar o objeto.

```php
require_once '/path/to/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
```

Recomendo colocar no arquivo /app/start/global.php

Fonte: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#install-with-composer